# Cyrillic encoding issue when importing csv to mySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, csv, encoding, utf-8

I experience the following problem: I've imported a csv file which contains records in Cyrillic, done that by using HeidiSQL db browser. I had opened the .csv with notepad and change the encoding to utf-8, then created the database with phpmyadmin with collation set to UTF-8_general_ci.

[HeidiSQL import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW7F0.jpg)

When importing I've selected UTF-8 encoding, after import everything looks fine in HeidiSQL and phpmyadmin, I mean that everything is readable, but not readable in my index.php file where also the encoding is set to utf-8 via 
`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
[Browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsySm.jpg)
I don't know where is my mistake.

Here's my index.php code:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
<?php include 'config.php'; ?>
<?php include 'header.php';?>


<?php
$db=new mysqli("$dbhost","$dbuser","$dbpass");
$db->select_db("$dbname") or die ("Critical error: Could not connect to database!");
$query="select * from books";
$result=$db->query($query);

//find number of rows
$num_rows=$result->num_rows;

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
?>



<div id="box">
<center>

<form id="search" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder"Search your book..."/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
<br>
<h3>Our Books</h3>
<table border="1">
<tr id="table_header">
<td>Author</td>
<td>Title</td>
<td>Publisher</td>
<td>Year</td>
<td>Edition</td>
<td>Location</td>
<td>Holder</td>
<td>ISBN</td>
</tr>



<?php
$total=0;
$tstoke=0;
$tout=0;
for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
{
    //fetch  row
    $row=$result->fetch_row();
    $total=$total+$row[2];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width=\"150\">$row[1]</td>" ; 
    echo "<td width=\"250\">$row[2]</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"100\">$row[3]</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">$row[4]</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">$row[5]</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">$row[6]</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"100\">$row[7]</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">$row[8]</td>" ;
    $stoke=$row[2]-$row[3];
    $tstoke=$tstoke+$stoke;
    $tout=$total-$tstoke;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">$stoke</td>" ;
    echo "</tr>";
}   
echo "</table>";    
?>
</center><br>
<center>Now We Have : <?php echo $num_rows; ?> Defreent Books >> Total Books : <?php echo $total; ?> >> Total Stoke : <?php echo $tstoke; ?> >> Total Out : <?php echo $tout; ?></center>
<br>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</center>
```

Comment: Okay so from the sounds of it, if you are able to look up the data from PHPMyAdmin, then I would say there would be an issue with your PHP file. Can you post your whole code file for review.

Comment: I've added the whole code of my PHP file. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem previously and found one solution:

```
mysqli_set_charset($db,'utf8');
```

and you have to use `htmlentities` whenever you print your db values..

i.e. your updated for loop is

```
echo "<table>";
for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
{
    //fetch  row
    $row=$result->fetch_row();
    $total=$total+$row[2];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width=\"150\">htmlentities($row[1]);</td>" ; 
    echo "<td width=\"250\">htmlentities($row[2]);</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"100\">htmlentities($row[3]);</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">htmlentities($row[4]);</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">htmlentities($row[5]);</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">htmlentities($row[6]);</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"100\">htmlentities($row[7]);</td>" ;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">htmlentities($row[8]);</td>" ;
    $stoke=$row[2]-$row[3];
    $tstoke=$tstoke+$stoke;
    $tout=$total-$tstoke;
    echo "<td width=\"30\">$stoke</td>" ;
    echo "</tr>";
}   
echo "</table>";
```

let me tell you one thing, you have to set your character set by this function only so that it will use for your current database connection.

The header is for your page not for your database.

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, the updated script didn't solve the problem. I've added `mysqli_set_charset($db,'utf8');` directive and use htmlentities, but still no result, now as a result I've got: `htmlentities(??????? ????????);`

Comment: can you give me one favour, give your input string to me i.e. some Cyrillic records here in comments please.....sorry for late reply...

Comment: No problem, here you are some strings `841516,Нели Маданска  Николова,Дружествени спорове и съдебни производства по закона за търговския регистър.,ИК Труд и право,2012,15th,,Бистра,9.78955E+12` and you can download the csv file with example data from here [link](http://www.dgkv.com/upl/strip_down.csv)

Comment: try this line `mysqli_set_charset($db,'cp1251');`  in above code...this code is used for windows cyrillic

Answer (score 0):

Don't use mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` interfaces!

utf8 needs to be established in about 4 places.

- The column(s) in the database -- Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to verify that they are explicitly set to utf8, or defaulted from the table definition.  (It is not enough to change the database *default*.)
- The connection between the client and the server.  See `SET NAMES utf8`.
- The bytes you have.  (This is probably the case.)
- If you are displaying the text in a web page, check the `<meta>` tag.

What probably happened:

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

Note: `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');` did not work because your connection is via the `mysqli_*` interface.